# Left join with 1 result for each row in the left table - without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables: (I deleted irrelevant fields)

Traffic: id, impressions, country

Events: trafficID,sells

For each traffic row there might be 0 or more rows in events.
When selecting all rows from traffic table + left join the events table to get the total SUM of sells for each traffic row - some rows in the result set will be duplicate because there are few traffic rows with more then 1 event.

The easy solution is GROUP BY traffic.id.
Now lets say I want to group by country, and select the SUM of impressions and sells for this specific country, If I would GROUP by traffic.id I won't get the result set I want - and if I won't group by traffic.id I will get duplicate traffic rows and thus wrong SUM result.

Any elegant way to solve this? I am using php pdo mysql, innodb engine in case it is relevant.

Comment: If you want to group by country, you group by country; if you want to group by "traffic rows", then group by that; they are separate queries.

Comment: @Uueerdo If I group by country I get multiple rows of traffic, so SUM(impressions) return the wrong value because it calculates some rows more then once.

Comment: It should not calculate any rows more than once; all `GROUP BY`s should operate on the same ungrouped results. Since a `traffic` cannot be in more than one `country`, it cannot be counted more than once. If the `GROUP BY country` is counting traffic rows' event(s) multiple times, the `GROUP BY traffic.id` must also be counting those multiple times.

Comment: @Uueerdo I am not guessing... I tested both types of queries on my DB. Unless I have a serious flaw in my DB tables this behavior is happening in front of my eyes :) I just selected COUNT(DISTINCT traffic.id) with GROUP BY county and got more ids then I got in the traffic table! When I truncate the events table I get correct results...

Comment: @Uueerdo I was sure this is the case as well, but please notice that when grouping by country, SUM(impressions) has to calculate 2 layers of data, it is actually SUM(SUM(traffic.id)) theoretically, and it just won't go to the second layer.

Comment: Were the queries different in any other way? That definitely seems strange. The only way I see that happening is if the country grouping was a left join, and the traffic.id grouping an `inner` one (or had a where that made it effectively inner). It would probably be a good idea to post your actual queries and a sample of the results you are getting. _In case it was not a typo.... it is highly doubtful "SUM(SUM(traffic.id))" would give you anything meaningful._

Comment: The different is one is grouped by traffic.id and one is not.
I might post the queries but I am afraid it will make things complicated, a lot of unrelated fields over there. maybe I will post a short relevant version.
"SUM(SUM(traffic.id))"  was a try to explain the case theoretically :)

Comment: Just a fix, when I selected COUNT(traffic.id) and grouped by country I got more IDS then I have in the traffic tables.

Comment: That is expected then, it is giving you the total results of the join that fall under that country; `count`ing  any field(s) without the count containing distinct is basically a "result rows grouped" count.

Comment: No, it gives me more rows then the table I am selecting from (traffic), this is unwanted behavior as far as I concern, actually I was quite sure SUM will fix this issue but it doesn't. it acts like I am joining the events table but I am not, I am just left joining it. I thought that SUM with left join will result in distinct rows from the left table and SUM of the right table but this is not the case - you have to use group by id which mess my result when I want to group by something else then id.

Comment: Just a clarification, when grouping by country I get the right amount of countries, but when printing the sum of ids used to calculate those rows I get more rows then I should. This is what I called "second layer" and this is what I tried to explain with the theoretical SUM(SUM(impressions)) example.
So it ends with countries that has more impressions then they actually do.

Comment: It does not give you "more rows than the table you are selecting from" as you are not selecting from that table, you are selecting from the LEFT JOIN of that table with another. `GROUP BY` determines the "distinct"-ness of the aggregate function results, not the `JOIN`ing; you could group on `sells` and count the distinct countries to see how many countries had each distinct sell value. ....I am still not sure why would you ever need to **sum** id values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the `Events` table prior to joining?

```
SELECT   t.country, SUM(t.impressions), SUM(e.totalSells)
FROM     Traffic t LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT   trafficID, SUM(sells) AS totalSells
           FROM     Events
           GROUP BY trafficID
         ) e ON e.trafficID = t.id
GROUP BY t.country
```

Comment: This will defiantly work but I try to avoid nested queries unless I have no choice at all, my tables are huge :) If no one will come up with a more elegant solution I will accept this answer. Thank you.